# Location of Intel's __assume affects performance

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, vectorization, intel

I am using an 8-th order finite difference time stepping function (for 2D acoustic wave equation) shown below.

I am observing substantial (up to 25%) performance increase from placing Intel's `__assume` statement inside the inner loop, compared to placing it at the beginning of the function body. (This happens regardless of number of OpenMP threads).

The code is compiled by Intel 2016-update1 compiler, Linux, with -O3 optimization option, and for AVX-capable architecture (Xeon E5-2695 v2).

Is it a compiler problem?

```
/* Finite difference, 8-th order scheme for acoustic 2D equation.
    p       - current pressure
    q       - previous and next pressure
    c       - velocity
    n0 x n1 - problem size
    p1      - stride
*/

void fdtd_2d( float const* const __restrict__ p,
              float      * const __restrict__ q,
              float const* const __restrict__ c,
              int          const              n0,
              int          const              n1,
              int          const              p1 )
{
    // Stencil coefficients.
    static const float C[5] = { -5.6944444e+0f, 1.6000000e+0f, -2.0000000e-1f, 2.5396825e-2f, -1.7857143e-3f };

    // INTEL OPTIMIZER PROBLEM?
    //     PLACING THE FOLLOWING LINE INSIDE THE LOOP BELOW 
    //     INSTEAD OF HERE SPEEDS UP THE CODE!
    // __assume( p1 % 16 == 0 );

    #pragma omp parallel for default(none)
    for ( int i1 = 0; i1 < n1; ++i1 )
    {
        float  const* const __restrict__ ps = p + i1 * p1;
        float       * const __restrict__ qs = q + i1 * p1;
        float  const* const __restrict__ cs = c + i1 * p1;

        #pragma omp simd aligned( ps, qs, cs : 64 )
        for ( int i0 = 0; i0 < n0; ++i0 )
        {
            // INTEL OPTIMIZER PROBLEM?
            //     PLACING THE FOLLOWING LINE HERE 
            //     INSTEAD OF THE ABOVE SPEEDS UP THE CODE!
            __assume( p1 % 16 == 0 );

            // Laplacian cross stencil:
            //   center and 4 points up, down, left and right from the center
            auto lap = C[0] * ps[i0];
            for ( int r = 1; r <= 4; ++r )
                lap += C[r] * ( ps[i0 + r] + ps[i0 - r] + ps[i0 + r * p1] + ps[i0 - r * p1] );

            qs[i0] = 2.0f * ps[i0] - qs[i0] + cs[i0] * lap;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the first comment strictly accurate?  If you uncommented the `__assume` outside the loop, would it slow down even if you left the `__assume` inside the loop active?  And with the one in the loop commented, would having an early `__assume` make your code slower than with no `__assume` at all?  From the text it doesn't sound that way, so I think your all-caps comments should maybe say "doesn't help here", and "only helps here, not outside the loop", or something.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes, I tried placing `__assume` either on top or inside the loop, but not in both places at the same time.

Comment: Does this code work and this issue still happen with ICC13?  If so, you could put your code [on godbolt](http://goo.gl/3nrETr).  I tried, but it doesn't compile; maybe there's a compile option I'm missing?  Otherwise, just edit the disassembly for both versions into the question, so we can see what difference it makes to the autovectorization.  Of course, that won't tell us *why* it fails to optimize when the `__assume` comes outside the OpenMP pragmas, just *how*.  The slower case probably just emits more code to handle misalignment for `r*p1`.

Comment: I like your wording choice in the last edit.  "speeds up" is good.  Anyway, I don't have experience with ICC, other than occasionally looking at ICC13 output on godbolt for something I'm messing around with.  I don't have any suggestions for how to know where to put `__assume` to make it take effect.  Does it have any effect in the outside-the-loops location?  Benchmark, or compare the asm between no `__assume` at all vs. an `__assume` at the location that doesn't help.  If it's not working, probably the asm will be identical.

Comment: @PeterCordes I don't have ICC 13, and ICC 13 does not support OpenMP 4, so I couldn't use it anyway. Bad phrasing on my side: placing `__assume` inside the loop speeds up the code. Placing it on top gives same performance as when there is no `__assume` at all

Comment: @PeterCordes Compiler options I use: -std=c++11 -march=native -O3 -openmp

Comment: This is worth submitting to Intel premier support.

Comment: Fill a bug report. `p1` is a function argument that could not possibly alias with anything, there are no obvious reasons why the compiler could not propagate the `__assume` statement to the inner loop.

Answer (score 2):

I was pointed to the following on Intel website:

> Clauses such as __assume_aligned and __assume tell the compiler that the property holds at the particular point in the program where the clause appears. So the statement __assume_aligned(a, 64); means the pointer a is aligned at 64 bytes whenever program execution reaches this point. Compiler may propagate that property to other points in the program (such as a later loop), but this behavior is not guaranteed (it is possible that compiler has to make conservative assumptions and cannot apply the property safely for a later loop in the same function).

So when I place `__assume` at the beginning of the function body, the assumption is not propagated into the inner loops, which results in less optimal code.

Although, my expectation was reasonable: since `p1` is declared as `const`, the compiler could have propagated the assumption.